# Outlook web Addins with graph api

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, msal.js

I am trying to make Outlook web add-ins and want to use graph api in that, as on [SSO article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins) they mention this "add-ins that use SSO are not accepted in AppSource".
**Want to know how to get user based graph token to access the graph api in outlook add-ins.**

I used msal js auth flow for authenticating user [here the link](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js).
When this code runs in chrome login popup get block by browser and in IE/EDGE login popup doesn't show off due cross domain.

Also after allowing popup in chrome i am able to get "Id Token" but `acquireTokenSilent(requestObj)` doesn't give any response.
**Is there any other method by which i can get graph access token in outlook web add-ins.**
And last the complete add-ins deployment process on AppSource.

```
EDGE Error:
Error:  SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'https://outlook.office.com' failed to allow a cross-origin document resource at 
'ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge/assets/errorpages/forbidframingedge.htm#https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=89bee1f7-5e6e-4d8a-9f3d-ecd601259da7&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fwebshell.suite.office.com%2fiframe%2fTokenFactoryIframe&state=2fd6785e-ad7d-4ba6-b388-f258ee72a0e3&client-request-id=d5ebe7a0-d47e-4f80-b6c3-c92151ad9801&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.15&nonce=f8d6d0af-fcd0-41e2-b13f-cdd5081c4426&sso_nonce=AQABAAAAAAAP0wLlqdLVToOpA4kwzSnx_gNC04Yd8tQjotaaeZcmU-owjoPhrd8CGajva7JsLfGXbPo3Z4L-ij10hP0Ad2GUJyn8ZLnhiEhRZSHOQh-GdCAA&mscrid=d5ebe7a0-d47e-4f80-b6c3-c92151ad9801'.
```

Comment: Are you looking to submit your add-in to AppSource? Sideloaded add-ins should be able to use the Office.js SSO API. MSAL.js is not currently supported in Office add-ins.

Comment: Yes, I am looking to submit on AppSource but before that i need to use graph api. Can you explain bit more on Sideloaded add-ins should be able to use the Office.js SSO API.

Comment: Sideloaded add-in is when you test the add-in in local environment by using the functionality of "installing by manifest/installing by url". For Sideloaded add-ins SSO API works but for appsource it doesn't.

Comment: Unfortunately, currently we don't have any solution for this but yes if you can help us understand your scenario we can help you with the Outlook REST API's as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a token for using Outlook REST APIs using the getCallbackTokenAsync() method.

Check the following doc: [Use the Outlook REST APIs from an Outlook add-in.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api)

Comment: I think getCallbackTokenAsync() method gives token by which we can access all the api related to mail not related to graph api. and as mention in my question i need to use graph api in my add-ins

Comment: Any update on this matter? I am having the same problem in an AddIn I am working on. We need access to the MS Graph API through the Add-In, however msal.js does not work properly on Outlook Desktop nor Outlook Web on Edge.

Comment: By setting the permission in Manifest file as  “ReadWriteMailbox”, the REST API token will provide read and write access to mail, calendar, and contacts, including the ability to send mails. Let us know if this resolves the issue that you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue that MSAL.js does not work in iframes, e.g. for Office add-ins. We are currently working on fixing this, and are planning to have it resolved in an upcoming release.

Comment: Is there any other method by which i get graph access token in Outlook add ins?