# Outlook Addins with graph api

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We are currently using outlook rest api with  getCallbackTokenAsync() as suggested here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57518222/13983926

The outlook rest api is now deprecated. Is there a new suggestion or solution for connecting to graph api from office addins?

sideloading would not be an option, our addin is already public for 365 paid and free outlook customers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSO to obtain access tokens to call the Microsoft Graph API. Documentation on getting started with SSO can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins).

Please be sure to follow the format requirements in the manifest for SSO, or your add-in may be rejected from AppSource until it meets the required format.